# maven release:perform and parent pom

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a library which I "mavenized" recently and put into a local git repository.
In order to lock some plugin versions I created a simple parent pom which defines the plugin versions via **pluginManagement** (the parent pom file **is not** checked into any SCM repository). I specify the parent pom in my libraries pom file:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
 </parent>
```

I use default directory structure. 
When I try to perform a release using the release plugin I run into a problem.

`mvn release:prepare` runs fine however when I run mvn `release:perform` maven checks out the corresponding tag from my local git repository into the **target/checkout** folder and tries to run the deploy goal.
However the build fails with the error message that it can't find the parent pom file defined in my library pom file.
I assume that's related to the fact that maven tries to find the parent pom file in the **target** folder and it is not available there.
Is there an easy way how to solve this problem?

**Update**:
I have multiple unrelated GWT libraries which should share the common company parent pom file in order to specify plugin versions.
The parent pom is just used for defining some default versions and won't contain any module definitions because all GWT libraries are unrelated.
The GWT library are really simple and have no real dependencies to any other libraries apart from the default ones (gwt, junit)

**Update2**:
I solved the problem by installing the superpom into my local repository by running `mvn install` in the folder of my superpom.

Answer (score 0):

The first fail you did is not to versionise the parent pom where you defined the pluginManagement area. This is the first step you must do put the pom.xml which you like to use a parent. Secondly you have to put the information about the VCS into the scm area of that pom. After you cleaned up everything you must do a mvn release:prepare release:perform of the parent pom. After that you are able to use it as a parent in your other projects. Furthermore you should define the distributionManagement area in your parent pom.

Comment: Does the parent pom have to be in the same VCS as my library ? 
I have several unrelated libraries which should use this as a parent (company) pom and each of them is in a separate github repository. Do i have to put the parent pom in every of these repositories ? 
For a release of a library do I have to call the release plugin only on the parent pom or can I do it on the library pom's ?

Comment: The VCS has nothing to do with the pom (artifact) itself...Only you have to be aware of where to put the released artifact (parent pom) (usually a repository manager). The releasing of the library depends what kind of project your library is (multi-module build or a single module?)..May be you can give an example of lib strcuture.

Comment: these are single module's without any dependency to any other library.  (see my update). The company parent pom is just for pinning the plugin versions.